# Hiveql to find the address is null and fill the address

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am new to sql/hql.

I am having the below hive table to frame a logic as explained below:

```
Card_ID  Mid      Address                
------   -----   ---------------           
1000     201     MG Road,bangalore      
1000     301     MG Road,bangalore       
1000     401     null 
1000     501     null

2000     205     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi

2000     305     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi             
2000     405     null

3000     109     psk road

3000     809     psk road
```

This is a staging table created only with Card_id's having more than one Mid

Requirement:

1. Identify Card_id's having  mid address as null and not null ( I need to create a table with this set of values to let my client review. so please need a sql to create this request)
2. Fill the address column null value with other mid address under the same card_ID

Desired output :

```
Card_ID  Mid      Address                
------   -----   ---------------           
1000     201     MG Road,bangalore      
1000     301     MG Road,bangalore       
1000     401     MG Road,bangalore 
1000     501     MG Road,bangalore

2000     205     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi

2000     305     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi             
2000     405     Plot # 5, Indira Nagar, Delhi

3000     109     psk road

3000     809     psk road
```

Please can you guys help me to frame the hql/sql by step by step for my understanding so that I can get the above o/p deliverd to my client by tomorrow.

Comment: Hi All, As of now I need to Identify Card_id's having mid address as null and not null ( I need to create a table with this set of values to let my client review. so please need a sql to create this request) so my o/p caids are 1000 and 2000 and not 3000.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max()` as a window function:

```
select card_id, mid,
       max(address) over (partition by card_id)
from t;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon ,Thanks for the quick update .. I am really new to the sql. Could you please elaborate more on the sql steps as edited in my post.

Comment: Gordon, Can you please help me to frame a query to get/Identify Card_id's having mid address as null and not null  ( I need to create a table with this set of values to let my client review. Upon client review we will then map the address  null values with other mid address values falling under same card_id

Comment: @Raya . . . New questions should be asked as *questions*, not in comments.